# Using \theabspage from the 'perpage' package

Tags: page-numbering, perpage

After two compilations of the following example with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{perpage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[6][2]
Page~\theabspage, \theabspage, \theabspage, \theabspage, \arabic{abspage}.
\end{document}
```

I obtain this:

[image]

However, I would have expected to see the number **2** printed twice at the top of page 2, after the second compilation run. Am I having wrong expectations, or somehow misusing `\theabspage`?

In a kind of desperate attempt, I've also tried to put `\AddAbsoluteCounter{page}` in the preamble, same result.

My TeX distribution is TeX Live as shipped in current Debian unstable (`texlive-base` version 2018.20190227-2) and the log file written by pdfTeX says `perpage 2014/10/25 2.0`.

Comment: Presumably `abspage` has the same issue as the normal `page` counter: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wrongpn

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your comment! I believe I know what happens with the `page` counter, how paragraphs and pages are broken, etc. (read the TeXbook 'till chapter 27). From reading the `perpage` manual, I expected that after two passes, `\theabspage` would be up-to-date, but I'm not sure I really understand its textual definition from the `perpage` manual (it mentions `\page`, what's that? A typo, I guess). So, maybe I just don't understand the purpose of `\theabspage`, after all. That was the question. :)

Comment: no you can't use \theabspage like this, and the perpage package is for other counters, e.g. to get footnote references by pages.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks, your example works for me. :-) Back to `\theabspage`: is it possible to change the `page` counter in a non-monotonic way? Then would the purpose of `abspage` be to provide a monotonic counter incremented every time `page` is incremented?..

Comment: If I understand the documentation of `perpage` correctly then `abspage` is defined as `\AddAbsoluteCounter{page}`. And `\AddAbsoluteCounter{<counter>}` just defines a counter `abs<counter>` that is stepped up each time `<counter>` is stepped up. Since it is not reset by resets to `<counter>` it holds the absolute/total counter value. For `page` that seems to imply that `abspage` has the exact same issues as `page` w.r.t. its value in the first paragraph on a new page. `\theabspage` and `\page` could differ if you started your document with Roman page numbers and only later switched to Arabic 1

Comment: @moewe Ah, right, I hadn't thought about negative page numbers. Thus, even assuming `page` is monotonically increasing (after some initial setting in backmatter), having `page` start from a negative value but `abspage` start from 1, automatically following `page`, could possibly be a use case for `abspage`.

Comment: If you want to call this negative page numbers, then yes. It is not that unusual for people to want to reset their page numbers at certain points, so a robust and truly unique counter like `abspage` can be useful. This is especially useful for other objects where it is much more common to reset counters (like footnote counters per chapter or the like) particularly in the context of the `perpage` package, which resets all kinds of things per page.

Comment: Right, I should have said “negative page counter”, but you got the idea. I understand the use case for footnotes, figures, tables, etc. I had more difficulty understanding it for `page`, but I believe it is clearer now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Actually, I got a little confused in the previous comments. I have to find again where I've seen negative values of the page counter being turned into roman numerals, but standard LaTeX doesn't seem to do this (maybe that was just an example *macro* for a random counter in the TeXbook). And I misused the term “backmatter” [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483665/using-theabspage-from-the-perpage-package#comment1222835_483665) where I actually meant “front matter.” Sorry.

Comment: Indeed, the macro I had seen that turns negative values of the page counter (the `\count0` register) into roman numerals and nonnegative values into arabic numerals is the `\folio`macro of plain TeX, presented on p. 252 of the TeXbook. It is not a LaTeX feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the absolute page number e.g. with the zref package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zref-user,zref-abspage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[6][2]
Page~\zlabel{A}\zref[abspage]{A}, \zlabel{B}\zref[abspage]{B}, \zlabel{C}\zref[abspage]{C}, \zlabel{D}\zref[abspage]{D}, \zlabel{E}\zref[abspage]{E}.
\end{document}
```